# how to add traffic manager in front of front door

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-traffic-manager

Currently our traffic manager has web app's endpoint. In order to protect Ddos attack, we want to use front door with WAF and not change endpoint of traffic manager to mitigate impact. So we want to add a front door behind traffic manager. I could call front door endpoint "https://xxfrontdoor.b01.azurefd.net/api/health" with 200. But I called traffic manager endpoint "http://xx.trafficmanager.net/api/health" with 400 bad request. Here is how I add front door endpoint in Traffic Manager:
[image]

Here is my front door:
[image]

Could anyone know could these work?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend placing an Azure Front Door instance behind an existing Azure Traffic Manager.  If you want the DDoS mitigation and WAF benefits of Front Door the proper path will be to configure your new Front Door instance to use the same endpoint the Traffic Manager is currently pointing to, then move your DNS from Traffic Manager to Front Door.

It's a [best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/best-practices#avoid-combining-traffic-manager-and-front-door) to not combine Front Door and Traffic Manager.